# Combinatorics-Number Theory Problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A positive integer is written on each vertex of a pentagon, a different one on each vertex. On each side is written the $lcm$ of the numbers of the vertices that form that side. If $n$ is written on each side, what is the minimum possible value of $n$?

Comment: What do you know about the number of prime factors of $n$?

Comment: It is the total number of different prime factors of the five numbers in the vertices.

Comment: What else? Can it be $0$? $1$? $2$?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution Sketch

First prove that $n$ cannot be a prime power, otherwise consider the sides incident to the smallest power. So $n$ has at least two prime factors $p,q$.

Next consider the case where $p,q$ are the only prime factors of $n$. If $p^2 \nmid n$, then there are at least 3 vertices with the same number of occurrences of $p$ in their factorization. It cannot be that there are 4 such vertices, otherwise they must have different powers of $q$, and splitting them into pairs gives different LCM, a contradiction. Therefore there are exactly 3 of them.

The other 2 must also not be adjacent, otherwise their LCM would be different, and the distribution $(1,p,1,p,1)$ is impossible, leaving essentially only $(p,1,p,1,p)$, since rotation is irrelevant. Now if the first vertex has the highest power of $q$, then the third vertex has a lower power of $q$ and so the second and fourth vertex must have the highest power, which makes them equal, a contradiction. Therefore the first vertex and by symmetry the last vertex do not have the highest power of $q$, and thus their LCM is not $n$, a contradiction. Therefore $n \ge p^2 q^2 \ge 36$.

But there are many solutions with $n = 2⋅3⋅5$, which is the smallest possible where $n$ has at least $3$ prime factors. I'll leave you to find one such solution.

Comment: @Hwai-RayTung: The trick is to show that if we only have two prime factors then each must occur at least twice in $n$, which makes $n$ bigger than what you can get with three prime factors. However, it is possible to achieve $36$ via $(4,2⋅9,4⋅3,9,4⋅9)$.

Comment: Nice solution. Looks like a general way of finding a least natural number $n$ satisfying some condition :)

Comment: A question: why do there have to be exactly three vertices with the same number of occurences of $p$? or do you mean 'at least'?

Comment: is it always impossible to have $n$ in the pentagon?

Comment: @M.Van: Well it's not as general as you might think. It only works when we're interested in the multiplicative structure of the natural numbers. And yes my argument started off as "at least three" but I forgot to exclude the "four" case. And I just noticed a typo (a stray "8").

Comment: @M.Van: I think all the solutions with $n = 30$ do have $n$ in the pentagon. At least those I found.

Comment: @M.Van: Ok I've added an argument for why there cannot be 4 vertices with the same power of $p$. And yes all solutions where $n$ is a product of 3 distinct primes must have $n$ in the pentagon.